# AngularJS ng-show animation triggered on data.$resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ng-animate, ng-show

Using ngAnimate, I'd like to animate an element that's only displayed when a $resource return data is resolved. So far I've tried:

```
<h3 ng-show="data.$resolved" class="animate-show">My Devices: {{deviceList.length}}</h3>
```

But the element pops into view instead of fading in when the data is resolved.

If I change the markup like below, it I'm able to fade the element by toggling the checkbox.

```
<h3 ng-show="showMe" class="animate-show">My Devices: {{deviceList.length}}</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showMe"/>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue with animation. What I did was:

When I got the data, I delay the show to the next cycle using $timeout

```
data.$promise.then(function() {
    $timeout(function () { $scope.showMe = true; }, 0);
});
```

So that browser has time for rendering animation. I don't know exactly what it is but my guess is that Angular keeps a dirty loop to check for changes (yes, that what it does), so that binding to views can be triggered as quick as possible. So, a delay to next cycle will leave browser some time for animation.

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/df4Ss7?p=info)

Comment: Seems to produce mixed results for me. On roughly 20% of page loads the animation displays. Tried it in Safari and Chrome.